# Column created by error while adding a column from another file in r

Tags: r, merge

I don't why each time I add a column from another file, the code creates me another column with names X, X..1,X..2. I don't know where the values are coming from. This is the code i'm using:

```
file <- read.xlsx2(path1)
file
file0 <- read_excel(path2)
file0 <- file0[order(file0$Activity, decreasing = TRUE),]
file0 <- file0[!(file0$State == "Due Today"), ]
file0
file1 <- merge(file,file0, by.file ="Activity", by.file = "State", all = TRUE)
file2 <- sapply(file1, as.character)`
file2[is.na(file2)] <- ''
file2
```

This is what it gives me:

| Activity | State | X..3 | X..2 | X..1 | X. | X04.14.2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Soccer" | "0-3 Days" | "1" | "1" | "1" | "1" | "63" |
| "Basketball" | "1-3 Days" | "2" | "2" | "5" | "" | "" |
| "Baseball" | "4-8 Days" "3" | "3" | "2" | "2" | "9" |  |

The columns go on with dates just as the last one, but each time I add one it creates me that columns with the X...
I don't want those columns each time I add a new one. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like an header problem. Are you sure you have colnames in each file you read?

Comment: @Waldi yes, I even can apply filters in excel in the headers! And there's no other information besides the activity, state and date columns on each new file.